# How to see full query from SHOW PROCESSLIST?

Tags: mysql, processlist

When I issue `SHOW PROCESSLIST` query, only the first 100 characters of the running SQL query are returned in the info column.

Is it possible to change MySQL config or issue a different kind of request to see complete query (the queries I'm looking at are longer than 100 characters)

Answer (score 615, accepted):

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

If you don't use `FULL`, ["only the first 100 characters of each statement are shown in the `Info` field"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-processlist.html).

When using phpMyAdmin, you should also click on the "Full texts" option ("← T →" on top left corner of a results table) to see untruncated results.

Comment: It seems phpmyadmin does not care about this, and still shows the truncated info.

Comment: @giorgio79:  If I recall correctly, phpMyAdmin truncates all string results.  It's been four years since I did any web development, though, so I could very well be mistaken.

Comment: I'm seeing queries getting truncated after a certain length even when using `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`. Can I make it even fuller somehow?

Comment: the command `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` needs a semi-colon `;` at the end right?

Comment: @R.Haq If it's the only query you're going to do, then the semicolon is not necessary. If you want to do more than one query, then you do need the semicolon after each of them.

Comment: @JulioGarcia all right, but i failed to execute this single line query in mysql cmd interface without semicolon, might do something wrong there i guess.Thanks.

Answer (score 145):

Show Processlist fetches the information from another table. Here is how you can pull the data and look at 'INFO' column which contains the whole query :

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST where db = 'somedb';
```

You can add any condition or ignore based on your requirement.

The output of the query is resulted as :

```
+-------+------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| ID    | USER | HOST            | DB     | COMMAND | TIME | STATE     | INFO                                                     |
+-------+------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|     5 | ssss | localhost:41060 | somedb | Sleep   |    3 |           | NULL                                                     |
| 58169 | root | localhost       | somedb | Query   |    0 | executing | select * from sometable where tblColumnName = 'someName' |
```

Comment: This is probably the most useful answer.

Comment: My info column shows `COMMIT`. Do you know how I can view more details about the actual query?

Comment: localhost:41060 , what does 41060 stands for ? any guess ?

Comment: Quick query for showing actively running queries & the capacity to end a query on Amazon Aurora MySQL: ```select id pid, user, concat('CALL mysql.rds_kill(', id, ');'), time, state, info from information_schema.processlist where info is not null order by time desc;```

Answer (score 25):

**See full query from SHOW PROCESSLIST :**

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

**Or**

```
 SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST;
```

Answer (score 15):

I just read in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-processlist.html) that `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` by default only lists the threads **from your current user connection**.

Quote from the MySQL SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST documentation:

> If you have the PROCESS privilege, you can see all threads.

So you can enable the `Process_priv` column in your `mysql.user` table. Remember to execute `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` afterwards :)

Comment: This is not true if you are `root`.

Answer (score 15):

If one want to keep getting updated processes (on the example, 2 seconds) on a shell session without having to manually interact with it use:

```
watch -n 2 'mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u some_user -psome_pass some_database -e "show full processlist;"'
```

The only bad thing about the `show [full] processlist` is that you can't filter the output result. On the other hand, issuing the `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST` open possibilities to remove from the output anything you don't want to see:

```
SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST
WHERE DB = 'somedatabase'
AND COMMAND <> 'Sleep'
AND HOST NOT LIKE '10.164.25.133%' \G
```

Comment: This is the only answer that seems to have the key element needed to answer the original question, which is to get the `info` column without the query being truncated: terminating the query with `\G` instead of `;`

Comment: you might try using `mytop(1)`

Answer (score 7):

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

This shows the full processlist with more info.

Comment: I'm sorry but how is this different from the accepted answer?

Comment: I had a \G at the end of the command like this SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST \G But now it doesn't seem to work that way.. something changed?

Answer (score 1):

`bash`

```bash
## identify the query id
mysql -e 'SHOW processlist'

## show only the related sql query for this process omitting the other columns
## change: YOUR_QUERY_ID_YOU_LOOKED_UP
mysql -sre 'SELECT info FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE id=YOUR_QUERY_ID_YOU_LOOKED_UP'|tr '\n' ' ';echo

## bonus: get mysql EXPLAIN for this query (when its too long to copy properly)
## change: YOUR_DATABASE,YOUR_QUERY_ID_YOU_LOOKED_UP
mysql -e "USE YOUR_DATABASE;EXPLAIN $(mysql -sre 'SELECT info FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE id=YOUR_QUERY_ID_YOU_LOOKED_UP'|tr '\n' ' ';echo)"
```

`mysql`

```sql
-- identify the query id
SHOW processlist;

/*
show only the related sql query for this process omitting the other columns
change: YOUR_QUERY_ID_YOU_LOOKED_UP
*/
SELECT info FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE id=YOUR_QUERY_ID_YOU_LOOKED_UP \G
```