# How do you display the whole query in mysql "show processlist"?

Tags: mysql

The `Info` field of the output gets truncated a lot. How can I force mysql to show the whole query being processed?

```
$ mysql -uroot -e 'show processlist\G'
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     Id: 2672
   User: root
   Host: localhost
     db: plummelo_development
Command: Query
   Time: 173
  State: Copying to tmp table
   Info: SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `recipes`.`id` * 2 + 0 AS `id` , `recipes`.`title` AS `title`, GROUP_CONCAT(DIST
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to see full query from SHOW PROCESSLIST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638689/how-to-see-full-query-from-show-processlist)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html):

```
mysql -uroot -e 'show full processlist\G'
```