# How can I get a full list of all queries currently running on my MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL Administrator and MySQL Workbench to view my current threads and connections, and the query is shown within those apps, but it's just way too long and runs off the screen.

What is a simple way to see all queries no matter how long they are? Is there a simple SQL statement I can just run?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Run the following command in order to see full query in the output:

```
mysql>SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

Look for more information here:
[How to see full query from SHOW PROCESSLIST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638689/how-to-see-full-query-from-show-processlist)

In order to see all queries you MUST have PROCESS privilege.

Answer (score 5):

Run the following command:

```
mysql> show processlist;
```